# How to create a backup of rows deleted due to foregin key reference

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to save all rows get deleted from db in a different table , So once in a day i will run a php command and deleted all related files from server.

I have created a trigger to save deleted row in to a table and it working fine but table rows get delete due to foreign relationship not get save. 
I think triggers are not execute on rows get deleted due to foreign key constrain.

please help

Comment: It looks like the last sentence in the post is incomplete

Comment: Actually i want to remove all image name stored in db . for this i have to check in php and remove that file first and then i have to remove that row. 

At the place of that i am looking for a way to store all images name in a different table which going to delete . with the help of trigger i got success for table on which i have fire delete query , but tables child table rows also get delete due to foreign key cascade constrain and trigger applied on those child table are not get fired.

Comment: I changed your post because it showed up in the "Help and improvement" queue. A post only gets in that queue because **multiple people** triaged it as being in need of improvement. Grammar, spelling, use of punctuation in your post all have errors. You can of course put those errors back in, as you did, but it makes your question more difficult to understand than necessary. If possible let your (future) post be reviewed by a native speaker of English or at least someone with a better command of the language than you have. It increases your chances of getting the answer you're seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the trigger on your master table. It should backup all the child records first and then the master table record. Instead of having multiple triggers for all child tables you can try to achieve it using a single trigger.